# In ng2-chart, setTimeOut function is not working on firefox using angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using `setTimeOut` function for ng2-chart. when Reload the app ng2-chart data not show thats way I am using `setTimeout` function. In chrome browser, `setTimeout function worked and ng2-chart data show but in firefox browser, setTimeout not worked or ng2-chart data not show.

```
  ngOnInit() {
          this.service.getBuySellChartContent().valueChanges().subscribe(res => this.buySellChartContent = res)
          setTimeout(()=>{
             this.chartDataChange('week');
          },2500)
       }

chartDataChange(tag){
      for(var content of this.buySellChartContent){
         if(content.tag == tag){
            this.chartData = content;
         }
      }
   }

<div style="display: block" *ngIf="chartData">
   <canvas baseChart
      [datasets]="chartData.data"
      [labels]="chartData.label"
      [options]="chartData.lineChartOptions"
      [colors]="color"
      chartType="line">   
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: show your code so we can help you

Comment: Change set time out function like : $ref = this; setTimeout(()=>{
             $ref.chartDataChange('week');
          },2500)

Comment: If you have data loading issue then you can call you method in ngAfterViewInit life cycle.